# Mapview PixelConverter Error?

Tags: android

I am working on Mapview.I am getting error but i have no idea why i can getting this.I debug all of the item .I didnt  see it before.

Can anybody  see this error?I now it is null exception but can anybody see PixelConverter?

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.android.maps.PixelConverter.toPixels(PixelConverter.java:71)
    at com.google.android.maps.PixelConverter.toPixels(PixelConverter.java:61)
    at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onLayout(MapView.java:681)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:909)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```